# current spike of a momentary toggle circuit

Tags: toggle-switch

The toggle circuit below works well, but I noticed that there will be current spike when the switch is closed, i.e., when switch is closed, the two caps will charge each other without resistor in between, the energy is small, but current will spike.

Is it necessary to add a 1k resistor between the 0.01uF cap and the ground?

Or is the 0.01uF cap redundant and can be removed? (I assumed it is added to ensure the toggle is on OFF state when power on, but seems not really needed).

[image]

http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/electronic-circuits/push-button-switch-turn-on/latching-toggle-power-switch

Comment: That 0.01uF capacitor is probably for decoupling purposes.

Comment: Where are you detecting the current spike and how are you measuring it?

Comment: Good question, I can only measure the the voltage step change across the cap (0.01uF), just theoretically assume Ohm's law still applies in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a small resistor like 82 or 100 ohms in series with the switch. The small resistor will limit the current flow spike that would occur when the switch is initially closed. Select the resistor size do the current surge is controlled but at the same time not having much effect on the normal behavior of the circuit.

Comment: Hi @Michael can you also explain how you arrived at this logical deduction so that it will be useful for other members as well.